# Can't add Google Places API key

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Apologies if this is a simple question but I can't seem to add my Google Places API key to Xcode with the syntax showing an error.

I assume I add it as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyC3XTKEp28ugdIwO1Zz7wv3uSPw1reTGeI"]; (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone is able to give me the correct syntax as instructions on the Google Developer section are pretty vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to provide your API key inside of the method body.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"ABC123"];
    return YES;
}
```

Side note: Don't share your API Key. You don't want other people using it, do you? :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct syntax:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"APIKEY"];

    return YES;
}
```

here you can see the complete doc:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start